# Loop within custom post type generating the_title as text

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Looking for an ACF custom post type php junkie to help me with this. I couldn't find another question on here like this so I might be off as far as the best practice solution for this, but hopefully not!

Within a specific post type, I am trying to load another post type in a loop.

As a practical example here, within each neighborhood I want to list apartments dynamically.

My original idea was to do an ACF checkbox listing the neighborhood titles so the value property loaded the neighborhood's the_title dynamically.

This worked, but for some reason the load also pulls in the_title as text above the loop.

Thoughts? (code below)

```
        <?php

        $apartments = query_posts(array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'apartment_neighborhood',
                    'value' => the_title(),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
            ),
            'post_type' => 'apartments', 
            'orderby'=> 'title', 
            'order' => 'ASC' ));
        $loop = new WP_Query( $apartments );

        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_the_title();` as it return the value while `the_title();` prints it

```
 <?php

        $apartments = query_posts(array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'apartment_neighborhood',
                    'value' => get_the_title(),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
            ),
            'post_type' => 'apartments', 
            'orderby'=> 'title', 
            'order' => 'ASC' ));
        $loop = new WP_Query( $apartments );

        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

**Refer Here**

**[Get The Title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)**

Comment: Well that was simple. Thanks!